# Why does the table data only load after inputting a search into the search box?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, knockout.js

I have a sharepoint list with a search box at the top of it. The data only loads after I input anything at all into the search box and I can't figure out why. It's using Knockout

HTML:

```
<input placeholder="Search…" id="searchInput" type="search" name="q" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off">
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: ideas">

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.IdeaNumber"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.IdeaTitle"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.IdeaStatusValue"></td>
        .....
        <td></td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

ViewModel:

```
var viewmodel = {
    query: ko.observable("")
    };

viewmodel.ideas = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
        var search = this.query().toLowerCase();
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(ideaArray, function(idea) {
            return idea.IdeaTitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
        });
    }, viewmodel);
```

Any suggestions would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your settings for the input:

```
data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"
```

Here is the `Update` being set to `keyup` event, which is firing only after entering some data.

Refer the [Knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) for all possible values:

- `input` - updates your view model when the value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element changes. Note that this event is only raised by reasonably modern browsers (e.g., IE 9+).
- `keyup` - updates your view model when the user releases a key
- `keypress` - updates your view model when the user has typed a key. Unlike keyup, this updates repeatedly while the user holds a key down
- `afterkeydown` - updates your view model as soon as the user begins typing a character. This works by catching the browser’s keydown event and handling the event asynchronously. This does not work in some mobile browsers.

If you want some value to be shown in your textbox initially, you can change your `viewmodel`:

```
var viewmodel = {
  query: ko.observable("Search here...") // will populate the textbox
};
```

Comment: Hi, what the issue is, is that for the data to load in the table I need to enter in a value into the search box. I want it to show all the data and then the search to obviously narrow down the fields. The way it's looking now, unless I type anything in to the search field the table below is empty.

Comment: @KieranHanna Did you get into the `viewmodel.ideas` function in the debug?

Comment: when i load it with that code there's nothing in the array but when I use this code viewmodel.ideas = ko.computed(function() {
   var search = this.query().toLowerCase();
   if (search == "") {
       return ideaArray;
   } else {
       return ko.utils.arrayFilter(ideaArray, function(idea) {
           return idea.IdeaTitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
       });
   }
}, viewmodel);
the array is now full but there is still nothing showing up.